# Python colorama not working with input?

Tags: python-3.x, colorama

Finally got colorama working today, and it works excellent when printing strings, but I got the common error everyone seems to get when I attempted to use colorama with input.

Here's my code:

```
launch = input(Fore.GREEN + "Launch attack?(Y/N): ")
```

Screenshot of output:

[image]

Comment: What OS and Python implementation are you using?

Comment: Did you remember to call `init` first?

Comment: Response to my own comment: No, I get this problem too in 3.X, even if I do `init()`. Works fine in 2.7 though.

Comment: Using Windows 10 64 bit Python 3.5.0

Comment: Yes, I have called init without anything in it.

Comment: There there was no useful answer here I filed a bugreport at https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/103

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue (Python 3.5.4) and, just in case it is not too obvious for somebody else looking at this, you can always rely on the workaround of combining print / input calls where you previously had just an input call:

```
print(Fore.GREEN + "Launch attack?(Y/N): ", end='')
launch = input()
```

This should produce the exact same output as in your question, with no extra blank lines and with the code coloring working without the need of importing anything else.

The (small?) disadvantage is that you you will end up with two lines of code where you previously had just one.

Answer (score 4):

On my system, `input()` works with colors *if* you add

```
import sphinx.quickstart
```

to your module.

So here is the full code.

```
from colorama import Fore
import colorama
import sphinx.quickstart
colorama.init()
launch = input(Fore.GREEN + "Launch attack? (Y/N): ")
```

(This leads to two questions:

1. Why does it not work in the first place?
2. What is the actual reason? – Someone might like to dive into the sphinx source code.)

---

*N.B. if you run python via `winpty` from **Git Bash**, set `convert`.*

```
colorama.init(convert=True)
```

Otherwise, you do not get color with the current versions.

Comment: I hope this gets figured out. I would really like to use this now for a script. Importing `sphinx.quickstart` worked, but it added an extra 18 Megabytes to my compiled exe Python script.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this problem in the starting of the code add

```
import os

os.system('cls')
```

This will clear the screen and hence clear all the external factors blocking the colorama in input.
This works ***100%*** you just need to do it once in the starting of the program [or just before the first use of colorama with input] and after that use **colorama** in any creative way you want to.

I hope this will help all the creative minds trying to make their codes more colourful

Answer (score 0):

just make sure about the 'autoreset' in init()

```
init(autoreset=True)
```