# How to apply coloring/formatting to the displayed text in input()-function (similar to print statement formatting)?

Tags: python, formatting, string-formatting, windows-console, colorama

I have a small game application, which is started from the Windows console (cmd.exe). I am able to format the text in any desired way using ANSI escape sequences.

I would also love to apply formatting to the text from the `input()`-method, but I have not found a way how to do so. Here is the testing code...

```
from colorama import init
init(autoreset=True)

RED = "\x1b[1;31;40m"

print(f"{RED}This text is red\n")

not_red = input(f"{RED}Insert some random stuff: ")
```

in my windows console, you will see that the ANSI sequence is displayed as a simple string in the input statement:

[image]

whereas in my Spyder IDE console, it has the reverse effect:

[image]

Can anyone explain the displayed behaviour in the different consoles to me?
And is there any way to format the `input()`-text in the Windows cmd console? This is where my program is run normally and I would like to make it even prettier :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872612/python-colorama-not-working-with-input) unfortunately I cannot flag as a duplicate due to the open bounty

Comment: ANSI codes work directly with input in OSX (tested in jupyter notebook, python 3.6)

Comment: interesting link, I'll take a look. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colorama` works by [replacing `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) with versions that interpret ISO 6429 sequences, make appropriate Win32 calls to implement them, and send the rest of the characters on to the underlying stream.  This explains your observations: `input` doesn’t use the Python-level `sys.stdout.write`, and Spyder interprets the sequences itself but is unaffected by the Win32 calls.

The only reasonable fix seems to be to use `input` with no prompt; you shouldn’t need to do any more than `print` your prompt with no newline (a trailing `,` in Python 2 or `end=""` in Python 3).