# display the user input text in color in the windows cmd

Tags: python, formatting, colorama

I have yet another question regarding my little console program for the windows cmd.

I use colorama to color my text in the terminal which makes it look like this:

[image]

Then I found out how to color the text in an `input()`-method using a little "hack" with a print without linebreak, like this:

```
from colorama import init
init(autoreset=True)
YELLOW = "\x1b[1;33;40m" 

print(f"\n{YELLOW}Turnier spielen? [T]: ", end='')
tournament = input()
```

this leads to the yellow line in the picture above.

But I still look for a way to color the very characters the user inputs - so here I would like to format the user input "sdffdgf..." in color as well.

[image]

has anyone a solution for me or will it just not be possible with the limited windows cmd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the `init(autoreset=True)` line from your code runs as you wish on my machine.

```
import colorama

from colorama import Fore,Style,Back
colorama.init()

YELLOW = "\x1b[1;33;40m" 
RED = "\x1b[1;31;40m"

print(f"\n{YELLOW}Turnier spielen? [T]: ", end='')
tournament = input()
print(f"\n{RED}Turnier spielen? [T]: ", end='')
tournament2 = input()
```

[image: code together with output to see it working]

My colorama version `colorama==0.3.9`.

The [Colorama docs](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) state that when using `autoreset=true` it will reset your colour and styling options immediately after the `print` command, this happens before you get to your input command which is why you do not get the colours in the user typed text.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for this late yet gold answer! I never suspected it to be caused by the autoreset....looks like I have to `{CLEAR}` after every line, then I can omit the `autoreset=True` altogether and finally get my colored inputs :-)!

Comment: @Cut7er you might even benefit of creating your own print function instead of adding the `{CLEAR}` to every line `print(f"\n{YELLOW}Turnier spielen? [T]: ", end='')`, you could pass the desired string and colour as parameters and have the print statement in the function itself. That's personally how I would do it

Comment: definitely an idea worth looking into! thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

You can pass `input()` a string to display before the actual input of the user.

```
from colorama import init
init(autoreset=True)
YELLOW = "\x1b[1;33;40m"
RED = "\x1b[1;31;40m"

print(f"\n{YELLOW}Turnier spielen? [T]: ", end='')
tournament = input(RED)
```

You can probably get rid of the `print(..., end='')` call with this.

Comment: that particular idea came to mind very soon, and was answered in my last question on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102240/how-to-apply-coloring-formatting-to-the-displayed-text-in-input-function-simi - but since `print()` and `input()` do not use the same underlying mechanics, it does not work. So if I insert the {RED} into `input(f"{RED}")`, it will just display the ANSI string and will not apply any formatting to the inputted words.

Comment: How about turning off `autoreset` and doing this :

`print(f"\n{YELLOW}Turnier spielen? [T]: {RED}", end='')` ?

Comment: sorry, not working - without autoreset, nothing is colored anymore. And I tried basically anything with placing the ANSI sequences before, after the text, inside print, input... there needs to be something completely different which I'm missing :|